# System.ApplicationException: Cannot open file

Tags: system

I have an application that needs to open an excel file.  However, when I run it, i get this error.  I have already granted all permissions necessary to the file and the folders housing the file.  Are there any other causes for this exception?  My application is built on Visual Studio 2005 in VB and it is housed on a windows 2003 server.  I've already tried refreshing the IIS as well.

Thanks!

Jennifer

Comment: It could work on your machine because you have Excel installed on it, and then not work on the server because Excel isn't installed there.

Comment: I just checked and Excel is installed on the server.  Same version as well. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the application on the server was pointing to a different version of the spreadsheet where the columns had been modified.  I copied the spreadsheet that was on my local machine and copied it on to the new server (renaming the previous spreadsheet).  Once the application was pointing to the correct spreadsheet, it worked.